# R highfrequency package

Tags: r

I'm newbie to R, I'm using it for my thesis on trade classification 
algorithms. 
I've some problems with the package `highfrequency`. 
I've converted my txt data in `xts` format using the code:

```
library(highfrequency) 

library(timeDate)

from="1990-11-01";

to="1990-11-02";

datasource = "~/raw_data";

datadestination = "~/xts_data";

convert(from, to, datasource, datadestination, trades=TRUE, quotes=FALSE,

ticker=c("ALO"), dir=TRUE,  extension="txt",header=FALSE,tradecolnames=NULL,
quotecolnames=NULL, format="%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S");

xts_data = TAQLoad(tickers="ALO", from="1990-11-01", to="1990-11-02",trades=T, quotes=F,datasource=datadestination)
head(xts_data)
```

but then when I load them on the console they appear like this without giving 
me

```
                    SYMBOL EX PRICE SIZE COND CORR G127
<NA>                ""     "" ""    ""   ""   ""   ""  
1970-01-01 01:00:01 ""     "" ""    ""   ""   ""   ""  
1970-01-01 01:00:00 ""     "" ""    ""   ""   ""   ""  
1970-01-01 01:00:00 ""     "" ""    ""   ""   ""   ""  
1970-01-01 01:00:01 ""     "" ""    ""   ""   ""   ""  
<NA>                ""     "" ""    ""   ""   ""   ""
```

nothing!

That's a problem I think because the next step I'd like to do is clean the 
data, I've tried with this code:

```
data("sample_tdataraw");

dim(sample_tdataraw);

tdata_afterfirstcleaning = tradesCleanup(tdataraw=sample_tdataraw,exchanges="N");

tdata_afterfirstcleaning$report;
```

but what I've to put `data("xts_data")`,`data("AC_trades")`?Because `sample_tdatarw` is generic,right?

I'm using quite old data (144 stocks NYSE TORQ from Nov90 to Jan91), they are 
the only free TAQ data that I could find, they're taken from a zipped file 
found in internet, they originally were in ASC format, that I could not read so 
I've opened it with txt and I've saved in this format, maybe the problem is due 
to the format of the data? They're like this (date,time,exchange,etc) but I've tried even with (ticker,date,time,exc,etc)

```
19901102  9:31:59  N  18.87500   2000         0   6139
```

Additionally, when I run the package highfrequency I get this messagge:

```
The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    as.Date, as.Date.numeric
```

Thank you for the help!!

Comment: This question is off-topic as it appears to be solely about why some R code is not working properly.

Comment: I cannot understand the answer

Comment: The code works, but I think it's me that I'm not organizing well the data or I do some mistakes in coding, I just need an hint

Comment: Sure, imo this is just not the optimal SE site to ask this. See here http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Crossposted on SO as well -- please don't do that.

Comment: I did not know is the first time I use these sites, SORRY!